# Makefile to compress all files in a directory

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've created a makefile with the following target:

```makefile
assets/css/%.css.br: assets/css/%.css
     brotli $< $@
```

This works really well for compressing every css file in a directory and creating a .css.br file.

However, how can I call this target to compress every css file in that directory, I can only call these targets one-by-one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Glob the names](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) of the CSS files, derive the names of the corresponding compressed files using [suffix substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html), and create a target that depends on all the compressed files:

```makefile
CSS_SRC        := $(wildcard assets/css/*.css)
CSS_COMPRESSED := $(CSS_SRC:.css=.css.br)

%.css.br: %.css
    brotli $< $@

compress: $(CSS_COMPRESSED)
```

Then

```bash
$ make compress
```

will compress each CSS file using your pattern rule.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'm making a small edit to your answer to add my original rule to make it crystal clear to a future reader both are needed.